# how to check in visual studio 2010 that a table is empty in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

i want to check if my table(in sql database) is empty so if it is i can put a button in place that allows the user to create their first ... well user so they can use the program.

so how do i check the user has no accounts then how do i add a new user keeping in mind that ID is a primary Key and is set to increase by one per user ,do i need to include that when adding the account some how?

summary = 
how do i add something to the table + do i need to include ID when adding it or do i need to ignore it and just add things like username and password.

secondly, how do i find out if the table is empty

<<<<< basic idea i understand now just this error is a problem >>>>>

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CheckNone = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) from Users",
            con);
            con.Open();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader Checkreader = CheckNone.ExecuteReader();
            if (Checkreader.Read())
            {
                if (0 != Checkreader.GetInt16(Checkreader.GetOrdinal("COUNT(*)")))
                {
```

it causes an error... something like this , indexoutofRangeException: COUNT(*)  so on
i think its because this line is wrong if (0 != Checkreader.GetInt16(Checkreader.GetOrdinal("COUNT(*)")))

specifically the name COUNT i have tried COUNT(*)

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CheckNone = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
        "IF EXISTS(SELECT * from Users) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0",
        con);
        con.Open();

        var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result==0)
        {
            //No users
```

This has the advantage (over using `COUNT(*)`) that, once the table *is* populated, you're not asking the server to count all of the rows when all you care about is whether rows exist or not (i.e. it more clearly states the fact you want to determine).

It also has the advantage that we don't open and then have to clean up a reader when all we care about is the first column of the first row of the result set - that's what [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) is built for.

Answer (score 2):

> > secondly, how do i find out if the table is empty

Change `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfRecords` then `ExecuteReader` or just leave the statement as it is and `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Users",con);

DataTable table = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(table);

if(table.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    //table is empty.
}
```

---

[SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter) example

Answer (score -1):

I would in code try to read the user table. Something like this

NOTE: This is psuedo code:

```
If not isdbnull(dataobject("nameoffield")
'''Do certain code
'''Show Button
ELSE
'''The user has an ID
'''Dont show button
END IF
```

As far as identity goes, you add an identity column to the table and it gets automatically generated. in the table you need to create it like this:

column name INT Identity(seed,increment)